# How to use awk to aggregate rows of data

Tags: awk, aggregate

I have a question, I have a set of data in rows which some rows are belong to a group.

E.g

```
Apple 0.4 0.5 0.6
Orange 0.2 0.3 0.2
Apple 0.4 0.3 0.4
Orange 0.4 0.5 0.8
```

The question is how can I automatically aggregate the columns accordingly using awk. In the past, I would easily deal with the following awk manually for each file..

```
awk '{col2[$1]+=$2; col3[$1]+=$3; col4[$1]+=$4} END {for(i in col2){printf("%s\t%.2f\%.2f\t%.2f\n",i,col2[i]/2,col3[i]/2,col4[i]/2)}}' myfile
```

But this time around the I am dealing with several files with different NF (number of fields) and I try to issue a command to automatically calculate the average of the group.
Eventually, we will have

```
Apple 0.4 0.5 0.5
Orange 0.3 0.4 0.5
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: how do you get Apple 0.4 0.5 0.5 ??

Comment: Oops, it should be 

Apple 0.4 0.4 0.5

Typo error. Apologies.

Comment: you're allowed to edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

here's something for a start.

```
awk '
{
    fruits[$1]++
    for(o=2;o<=NF;o++){
        fruit[$1 SUBSEP o]=fruit[$1 SUBSEP o]+$o
    }
}
END{
    for(combined in fruit){
        split(combined, sep,    SUBSEP)
        avg=fruit[ sep[1] SUBSEP sep[2] ]/fruits[ sep[1] ]
        f[sep[1],sep[2]]=avg
    }
    for(fr in fruits) {
        printf "%s ",fr
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
            printf "%s ",f[fr,i]

        }
        print ""
    }
}' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
Orange 0.3 0.4 0.5
Apple 0.4 0.4 0.5
```

Reference to gawk is [here](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html)