# awk pattern to multiple vlookup

Tags: awk, vlookup

I have following file:

```
    Diameter link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-1        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-1   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.243/3401     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.240.67/3401    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/1   
    
    
    Diameter link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-2        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-2   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.244/3402     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.240.67/3402    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/2   
    
    
    Diameter link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-3        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-3   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.243/3403     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.240.67/3403    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/3   
    
    
    Diameter link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-4        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztesbydra1-ocs-4   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.244/3404     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.240.67/3404    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/1   
    
    
    Diameter link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-1        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-1   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.243/2401     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.216.67/2401    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/2   
    
    
    Diameter link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-2        
    Diameter link state:     fine 
    TCP/SCTP link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-2   
    TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
    VRF name:                GxGyGa
    Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.244/2402     
    Dest IP/port number:     172.31.216.67/2402    
    Diameter link location:  STU/1/3   


Diameter link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-3        
Diameter link state:     fine 
TCP/SCTP link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-3   
TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
VRF name:                GxGyGa
Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.243/2403     
Dest IP/port number:     172.31.216.67/2403    
Diameter link location:  STU/1/1   


Diameter link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-4        
Diameter link state:     fine 
TCP/SCTP link name:      ztejktdra1-ocs-4   
TCP/SCTP link state:     active 
VRF name:                GxGyGa
Local IP/port number:    172.31.210.244/2404     
Dest IP/port number:     172.31.216.67/2404    
Diameter link location:  STU/1/2
```

I want to make it as csv format for easy readable format.

[image]

Bellow is my script:

```
$ cat parsing.sh       
#!/bin/bash`
awk '
 BEGIN { RS="\n";FS="[:/]"; OFS="," }
 NR==1 { print "PGW,Peer,IP PGW,Port PGW,IP DRA,Port DRA,vrf,Protocol" }
 /Diameter link name/ { tm = sprintf("%s",$2) }
 /Local IP/ { pl  = sprintf("%s,%s",$3,$4) }
 /Dest IP/  { printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n",tm,pl,$3,$4) }
 ' 30.txt
```

but the result is not as I expected:

```
$ ./parsing.sh 
PGW,Peer,IP PGW,Port PGW,IP DRA,Port DRA,vrf,Protocol
,     172.31.216.66,2414
```

please help me, why output is not as I am expected.

Thanks,

Budi

Comment: You could loop over the file and store each key/value pair in a 2d array, then at the end print it. Every time you see a blank line you start next record index. [a close-by solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091528/how-to-use-awk-to-aggregate-rows-of-data).

Comment: Essentially you could be storing each info in `array[recordnumber, keyname]`. Ex: `array[3, "VRF name"]`.   Then loop over recordnumbers and fields at the end. Or, you could output a temp array after each blank line seen. Maybe even simpler.

Comment: Replace the image with text so we can help you. We can't copy/paste an image to test with.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your input I find it best to first create an array to hold the tag to value mappings (`f[]` below) and then you can print, compare, change whatever values you like just by referring to their tags (names), e.g. using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NF {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
    next
}
tag != "" {
    print                               \
        f["Diameter link name"],        \
        f["Diameter link state"],       \
        f["TCP/SCTP link name"],        \
        f["TCP/SCTP link state"],       \
        f["VRF name"],                  \
        f["Local IP/port number"],      \
        f["Dest IP/port number"],       \
        f["Diameter link location"]
    delete f
    tag = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ztesbydra1-ocs-1,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-1,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/3401,172.31.240.67/3401,STU/1/1
ztesbydra1-ocs-2,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-2,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/3402,172.31.240.67/3402,STU/1/2
ztesbydra1-ocs-3,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-3,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/3403,172.31.240.67/3403,STU/1/3
ztesbydra1-ocs-4,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-4,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/3404,172.31.240.67/3404,STU/1/1
ztejktdra1-ocs-1,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-1,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/2401,172.31.216.67/2401,STU/1/2
ztejktdra1-ocs-2,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-2,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/2402,172.31.216.67/2402,STU/1/3
ztejktdra1-ocs-3,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-3,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/2403,172.31.216.67/2403,STU/1/1
```

Change the `print` statement to print whatever parts of whatever fields you like in whatever order you like.

Or if you just want to print all the values as CSV with the tags as headers then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NF {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
    tags[++numTags] = tag
    next
}
numTags {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=numTags; i++ ) {
            tag = tags[i]
            printf "%s%s", tag, (i<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for ( i=1; i<=numTags; i++ ) {
        tag = tags[i]
        printf "%s%s", f[tag], (i<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    numTags = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Diameter link name,Diameter link state,TCP/SCTP link name,TCP/SCTP link state,VRF name,Local IP/port number,Dest IP/port number,Diameter link location
ztesbydra1-ocs-1,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-1,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/3401,172.31.240.67/3401,STU/1/1
ztesbydra1-ocs-2,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-2,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/3402,172.31.240.67/3402,STU/1/2
ztesbydra1-ocs-3,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-3,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/3403,172.31.240.67/3403,STU/1/3
ztesbydra1-ocs-4,fine,ztesbydra1-ocs-4,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/3404,172.31.240.67/3404,STU/1/1
ztejktdra1-ocs-1,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-1,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/2401,172.31.216.67/2401,STU/1/2
ztejktdra1-ocs-2,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-2,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.244/2402,172.31.216.67/2402,STU/1/3
ztejktdra1-ocs-3,fine,ztejktdra1-ocs-3,active,GxGyGa,172.31.210.243/2403,172.31.216.67/2403,STU/1/1
```

Comment: As always, it was excellent and informative. Thank you. ++1

Comment: You're welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could do it.   Tailor the output to your needs, or output the columns individually by name instead of looping.

```
BEGIN{
  inblanks=1
}
(NR>1) && (/^[[:space:]]+$/){    # if we have a blank line consisting of only spaces.. and ignore leading blanks if any.
  if (inblanks==0){
    for (key in record){
       printf "%12s", record[key]
       }
   # -------- this will also work, for custom print:
   #  printf "%-20s", record["Local IP/port number"]
   #   etc, address record by name.
   #
       print
    inblanks=1    # avoid doing this for multiples...
    print "----------------"
  }
}
/[a-z]:[[:space:]]+/{    # any other content in form of  key:value
  inblanks=0    # reset blanks.
  split($0, a, ":")
  # -- trim variables (optional)
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"", a[1])
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"", a[2])

  # -- save to array
  record[a[1]] = a[2]
}
```

```
Example output for 4 records:

----------------
     active   STU/1/1   172.31.210.243/3401     ztesbydra1-ocs-1   172.31.240.67/3401           fine ztesbydra1-ocs-1              GxGyGa
----------------
     active   STU/1/2   172.31.210.244/3402     ztesbydra1-ocs-2   172.31.240.67/3402           fine ztesbydra1-ocs-2              GxGyGa
----------------
     active   STU/1/3   172.31.210.243/3403     ztesbydra1-ocs-3   172.31.240.67/3403           fine ztesbydra1-ocs-3              GxGyGa
----------------
     active   STU/1/1   172.31.210.244/3404     ztesbydra1-ocs-4   172.31.240.67/3404           fine ztesbydra1-ocs-4              GxGyGa
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU AWK

```
$ awk -F':' '
    /Diameter link name/,/Diameter link location/{
        gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$2)
        gsub(/\//,",",$2) 
        a[i+=1]=$2; 
        if(i==8){ 
            printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",a[1],a[6],a[7],a[5]
            i=0
        }
    }
' file
ztesbydra1-ocs-1,172.31.210.243,3401,172.31.240.67,3401,GxGyGa
ztesbydra1-ocs-2,172.31.210.244,3402,172.31.240.67,3402,GxGyGa
ztesbydra1-ocs-3,172.31.210.243,3403,172.31.240.67,3403,GxGyGa
ztesbydra1-ocs-4,172.31.210.244,3404,172.31.240.67,3404,GxGyGa
ztejktdra1-ocs-1,172.31.210.243,2401,172.31.216.67,2401,GxGyGa
ztejktdra1-ocs-2,172.31.210.244,2402,172.31.216.67,2402,GxGyGa
ztejktdra1-ocs-3,172.31.210.243,2403,172.31.216.67,2403,GxGyGa
ztejktdra1-ocs-4,172.31.210.244,2404,172.31.216.67,2404,GxGyGa
```

Comment: This solution is simpler. But it depends on output format to have a certain appearance: number of fields, and field order. Right ?

Comment: @MyICQ.. right.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` solution. Using regex `^[[:space:]]+Diameter link name:[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^:]+:[[:space:]]+([^\n]+)[[:space:]]+Local IP\/port number:[[:space:]]+([^/]*)\/([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Dest IP\/port number:[[:space:]]+([^/]+)\/([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Diameter link location:[^\n]+/` here which creates 6 capturing groups into array named arr and printing the values according to need.

```
awk -v RS=""  '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  print "Peer,IP PGW,Port PGV,ID DRA,vrf"
}
{
  while(match($0,/^[[:space:]]+Diameter link name:[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^\n]+[[:space:]]+[^:]+:[[:space:]]+([^\n]+)[[:space:]]+Local IP\/port number:[[:space:]]+([^/]*)\/([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Dest IP\/port number:[[:space:]]+([^/]+)\/([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+Diameter link location:[^\n]+/,arr)){
     print arr[1],arr[3],arr[4],arr[5],arr[6],arr[2]
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'   Input_file
```